# Can you programmatically change the style of a UITableView after it's been created?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

(This is about programatically swapping the style of existing tableview and not about setting table view style programatically)

I have a situation where I used a grouped table view in a view this table is editable and whenever it goes to editable view it gets displaced so what I thought was to change its style to plain whenever it goes to editing mode.

Is this possible? (Thanks in advance.)

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
MyIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell %d",indexPath.row];


 // MyIdentifier =@"tblCellView";
    NSString *offendersImagePath = [self applicationDocumentsDirectory];
    //NSLog(@"%@", dbPath);
    offendersImagePath=[offendersImagePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Images"];


CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
if(cell == nil) {
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = aCustomCell;
    aCustomCell=nil;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by displaced?

Comment: It seems you can't change table's style after table is created. But what exactly the problem is? post some code (e.g. cellForRowAtIndexPath method), may be it can be fixed another way...

Comment: or a screenshot of what you mean :)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

No this is not possible 
See this is wriiten in apple documentation:-

> **You set the table style when you initialize the table view (see
>   initWithFrame:style:). You cannot
>   modify the style thereafter.**

So you can not modify it afterwards...

Answer (score 2):

I dont think you can change the style of UITableView dynamically and set to plain or grouped. I think you have to do that while initializing it

`-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame style:(UITableViewStyle)style`

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution would be to have multiple UITableViewCell prototypes and switch them whenever necessary.

Comment: using different cell prototypes wouldn't affect whether the entire table is grouped or not.