# is it possible to change the style of uitableview in two different views?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

i have a table and i have also declared its style as grouped table style in view did load but i also have a button on click of which i want to change the style of the same table.

initially i was setting this in view did load method:

```
tableObj= [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,50,310,300)style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```

but on button click event i am setting tableview fram and style see below code

```
tableObj.frame=CGRectMake(5,50,310,300);

tableObj style=UITableViewStylePlain;
```

but it gives an error.....assignment to readonly property ??

Comment: Please check property in .h file change property readonly to readwrite

Comment: i have declare this...@property(nonatomic,retain) UITableView *tableObj;

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs, UITableView's `style` property is declared thus:

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly) UITableViewStyle style
```

That `readonly` keyword means that you can get the value of the property, but you can't set it. You can only set the style when you create the table using `-initWithFrame:style:`. This agrees with the error message you received:

> assignment to readonly property

Put simply, you can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
tblView.style;
```

It is a read-only property you cannot set any value to while you can only read it which is set.. You can check whether the property is changable or, not by writing your code as below

```
[tblView setStyle:];
```

But you will find that you can't do that, so you can't set.

Better you get 2 tableviews, or, reinitialize your existing tableview with different style.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the table view style like that. My advice use two tables or do something like this.

Initially it is like this:

```
tableObj= [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,50,310,300)style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```

Then when you want to change do this:

```
[tableObj removeFromSuperView];
tableObj=nil;]
//if not using ARC
[tableObj release];
tableObj= [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,50,310,300)style:UITableViewStylePlain];
[self.view addSubview:tableObj];
```

Comment: No it is not the best practice and I have said that in my answer too. See my edit now, I guess it is ok now??

Comment: Is it ok now?? Am I being correct with memory issues??@Sharma is it working?

Comment: @satheeshwaran I think you should pick a style (ARC or non-ARC) and stick with it. Don't try to do both at the same time -- you'll only confuse the issue.

Comment: @satheeshwaran: thanxsss it workss....

Answer (score 0):

According to the [UITableView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UITableView), you can not change the `style` of a `UITableView`

> When you create a UITableView instance you must specify a table style,
>   and this style cannot be changed.

Answer (score 0):

It possible to change the frame of table view dynamically but you can not change its style

> You set the table style when you initialize the table view (see
>   initWithFrame:style:). You cannot modify the style thereafter.

[UITableView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UITableView)

Answer (score -2):

See this.

[Can you programmatically change the style of a UITableView after it's been created?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5910251/can-you-programmatically-change-the-style-of-a-uitableview-after-its-been-creat)

No this is not possible See this is wriiten in apple documentation:-